# Grouping village points based on distance and population size using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

How do I group a number of villages based on their distance to each other and total cumulative population size?

I have a vector file of say 100 village points attached to atable containing data on population size and so forth. I want to group these villages such that each group contains 5-6 villages with the cumulative population of size of 5000. Hence, distance and cumulative population size should be used in my clustering of villages. I have used grouping in ArcMap 10.2 with no success. I have ArcMap 10.2.

Answer (score 16):

In terms of pseudo-code I am using these steps:

1. Define criteria for neighbours using spatial join 'one to many'. In this case it is the polygons that touch each other
   [image]
2. Connect neighbours by links
   [image]
3. Use network analysis package, e.g. networkx to build a graph, with weights for all links =1.
4. Define a number of groups (N) and iterate through combination of nodes, e.g. p=itertools.combinations(aBig, 2), where aBig is a list of all graph nodes.
5. Calculate totals of population closest to 1st and 2nd node in a pair. Compute ratio. Break, if it is equal to (N-1) within tolerance of course. The group with a smaller population is your 1st group.
6. Reduce N by 1  and go to step 5 if N>0, otherwise stop

This show 1117 polygons split into 5 groups with approximately equal population
[image]
and this - with more or less the same area
[image]

Note that multiple solutions are possible depending on start node. In the examples shown it was in the lower left corner.