# Clustering by property

Tags: postgis, postgresql, clustering

I have a number of points with a "time" property. I need a procedure that, given a total time, results in a number of clusters in which the sum of the time property do not exceed the given total time.

Example below shows a clustering when the given total time is 15:
Blue cluster is 15
Green cluster is 15
Yellow cluster is 15
Cyano cluster is 14

[image]

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far? Show your schema and data please. Edit the question to add more info.

Comment: I tried nothing cause I don't know where to start. Looked at some clustering tools like kmeans-postgresql but it do not completely fit my case since I want a cluster in which the sum of time property for each point in cluster must not exceed the given limit

Answer (score 1):

It is duplicate of multiple questions, but I post the answer because it is QGIS and there is not enough room in comments.

The pseudo-code explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size/123297#123297)
Step by step exercise can be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-10-2/153348#153348)

Exercise based on use of ArcGIS and python module called networkx.

It can be modified using QGIS providing it has a capacity of spatial join one to many. The only feature from networkx I've used is shortest path. This can also be replaced by small python function [e.g.](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/python/dijkstra.py)