# Clustering Technique?

Tags: spatial-database, clustering

I have the following 9 clusters (each colour represent the appropriate cluster):

[image]

I am looking for a **clustering algorithm** (if any) that would achieve "realistic" results.

The data represents Vancouver's bus stops, crossings, gates, stations etc (as you can see in the left side of the image).

I 've tried [K-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and I obviously had some bad results since it uses the Euclidean distance as its metric and that's not applicable in this scenario. I am using [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).

Answer (score 5):

The method and script described in [Graph/Network building and analysis of linked polygons in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/153094/115) are applicable to any network, e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have the referenced algorithm's description and/or pseudocode? It would be much clearer to me to understand what you are proposing.

Comment: Pseudocode description http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size/123297#123297