# Merging adjacent polygons to one which sum of attribute values of adjacent ones is between 1000 and 2000?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, merge, dissolve

I have a huge number of polygons that contain attribute field that represent number of offices inside each polygon. Now I want to merge all adjacent polygons which count (sum) of offices values is between 1000 and 2000. I want to do that using ArcGIS. I have idea to use Dissolve tool, Integrate tool and Merge tool, but I am not sure about steps in order to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graph/Network building and analysis of linked polygons in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop)

Comment: @FelixIP very similar, but not same.

Comment: 100 percent identical. If you dissolve result shown by rcvnode . Store you Shape s somewhere in Dropbox, I solve it in 10 minutes.

Comment: @FelixIP This is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0c62n0cy5nebwl6/TEXAS.zip?dl=0   If you can describe step by step what have you done in my example that would be great. JOINT_COUNT field is a field depending on which count I want to merge the polygons. Thx

Comment: @FelixIP This is great. But could you please send me a script that you have used in my example (with my parameters). Sorry, I am new in coding.

Comment: This will achieve nothing. First take an example and script from my 1st comment and make it work. In addition to script you'll need to learn how to attach it to tool, import networkx module and organise/name data accordingly. Let me know when done and I'll share slightly modified script I used today. I also preprocessed your data, i.e. fill 'water' gaps in a state of Texas(?). Note: the script already posted is a big present to anyone, there are no tools that are even close in ArcGIS package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took your polygons and converted them to single parts. For each part I recomputed number of offices pro rata of parts count in parent polygon. I applied procedure and script from the post mentioned in my comments with tolerance 0.05 and 316 groups, i.e. I tried to create 316 groups from 3059 original polygons with each group containing 1500 offices (total of offices=475169 ):

[image]

This is statistics of dissolved:

[image]

And these are [results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JFnxMmpGGsp7iv_ziykMv2T6PeT0yolg/view?usp=sharing). Note I removed islands because they have no neighbours in your definition.

For more information on algorithm, see [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size-using-arcgis-deskt/123297#123297).