# Combining parcels that are adjacent and add up to more than 10 acres

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, area, combine, summarizing

I am using ArcMap 10.7.

My task is to find a site to be developed for parking. Sites are supposed to be greater than 10 acres. But we can also look at adjacent sites that add up to 10 acres. I read something similar in this link:

[Merging adjacent polygons to one which sum of attribute values of adjacent ones is between 1000 and 2000?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264849/merging-adjacent-polygons-to-one-which-sum-of-attribute-values-of-adjacent-ones)

However, I have not been sure how to apply it. I have tried another rudimentary way which is to select parcels between 0 and 1 acre, then select parcels next to them, then select from them those which are 9+ acres. Then repeat the process from 1 to 2 acres, 2 to 3 acres, etc. However this is time consuming and this leaves a little room for error if say I get a parcel of .05 acres next to one that is 9 acres and they don't add up to more than 10.

I would love to just be able to do this all from the parcels layer. But if there's a way to create the "0 to 1 acre" layer and then select from the parcels layer something like "0 to acre parcels" acres + "parcels" acres >= 10"

Comment: Have you tried [Eliminate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm)?

Comment: @BERA  I haven't used eliminate, as I don't have the advanced license, just standard

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop

Answer (score 1):

I applied solution explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop) (that is exactly the same as in the post you mentioned) to 2820 parcels with total area of 231.5 ha and set target to 20 groups. Picture below shows resulting groups, labelled by their area in hectares:

[image]

It shows, that you can solve your task using above approach.

Note that it works on set of connected parcels only. Your chances are better with smaller parcels, so I suggest removing large (over 5 ha ?) first and work with the rest.