# Create shortest route for a set number of units

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network, road, route

I am running a field survey and would like to create routes for the surveyors. I have the building lots and road network for a particular city (road in red, lots in blue, with a Google Maps basemap):

[image]

Each of the lots may have more than one apartment unit, and the number of units is tracked as an additional column of the attribute table.

For routing purposes, I would like to generate routes of 50 units each for the surveyors. Is there a way to create a script (preferably in ArcGIS) that can iterate through the entire lot shapefile to create the most compact routes of 50 units at a time. Ideally, the output would be a new column in the lot shapefile that designates for each lot the route that it is assigned to.

Comment: Yes this can be done, use model builder to automate your network analysis. Suggest you explore the help file.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to ArcGIS - is there a particular tool in network analysis that can accomplish this task? The lots are a polygon layer and the road network is a vector layer.

Comment: I think you mean https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size-using-arcgis-deskt/123297#123297

Comment: Not quite. I would like to use the road network to map out the routes for each groups of 50 units, if possible.