# Dividing polygons into equal sub-regions based on population using QGIS?

Tags: census, population, redistricting

I'm using demographic data in California by census tract, and I'd like to be able to group those census tracts into 4 regions with an equal population in each region. Any recommendations for how to do this in QGIS?

I'd like to be able to do something like the process FelixIP takes in the answer to this question but I don't completely understand all of the steps: [Grouping village points based on distance and population size using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size-using-arcgis-deskt/123297#123297)

Any clarification to that answer as well?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size-using-arcgis-deskt/123297#123297