# Road network division and best maintenance facility location using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network, road, closest-facility

I am using ArcMap.

I have a national road network and I would like to divide it in several zones, so each zone would get the same amount of roads (from 150 to 250 km) - to get as equal zones as possible. Then, within each zone, I would like to find the best spot for roads maintenance facility, which would cover roads maintenance based on 1 hour driving distance.

I have tried ArcGIS Aggregate point to divide road network, Location-Allocation and Closest Facility from Network Analyst. The latter two, however, work only if I predefine roads maintenance facility location, which I wouldn't like to do in advance.
The facility must be located on a road network. And actually each location on road network represent an alternative for roads maintenance facility.

For sure, both tasks are interconnected - defining zones and defining the best location for maintenance facility, so maybe I haven't been solving it in the right order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Grouping of roads is very complicated task. Optimal solution will take ages to achieve.

I tried the idea explained in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size-using-arcgis-deskt/123297#123297) to [Grouping village points based on distance and population size using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289) on a set of roads totaling 368 km in length and attempted to split it into 5 'equal length' parts. Picture shows result:

[image]

As one can see results are reasonable, because length per individual group is not far away from the target of 368km/5 = 74km.

If you'd like to know more about the approach, I suggest to use script and do the exercise at [Graph/Network building and analysis of linked polygons in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094).

So here is your idea for first question. Second task is trivial if you'll manage to group roads. I suggest to remove facility related part before you post get closed.

Comment: That`s great suggestion @FelixIP. However, I am new to the tools you are mentioning in your answer to Grouping village points based on distance and population size using ArcMap - so - my kind request is - could you describe the procedure in more simple words + which tools you exactly used? Many many thanks!

Comment: Well, try harder, perhaps read second hyperlinked post. It also has working script. Very little I can do more. You'll also need Python skills, because script won't work with more than 5k nodes. Some minor modification required. Alternative - pay me, which is not cheap.