# Grouping points to clusters containing similar number of features using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, clustering, polygon-creation, grouping

**The question**

Using QGIS, how to cluster unevenly distributed points from the same layer to groups of about the same size / containing the same number of features?

**The problem**

I have a large point layer, containing more then 350'000 unevenly distributed features: buildings all over an administrative region containing cities, villages, as well as countryside. I want to split the layer in N (let's say: 500) separate layers, thus each containing ca. 700 features. Or, said otherwise, ideally would be to get any number of clusters, but each containing no less than 500 and no more then 1000 points - and being as compact as possible (no "gerrymandering" shapes).

**What I tried**

- First idea was to create a grid and create a separate layer of all points in the same grid cell. A 2*2 km grid resulted in cells containing between 1 and 2600 features.
- A second idea was to use K-means clustering. Cluster size, however, resulted in cluster size of between 13 and over 3600 features.

  Both solutions are not ideal, as each "cluster" should contain more or less the same number of features as can be seen on the screenshot, where each polygon contains between 24 and 31 points.
- I also tried GRASS v.cluster. I only got results using `density` clustering method, but that did not solve the problem, either.

*Simplified sketch to illustrate the problem: unevenly sized polygons ("clusters"), each containing between 24 and 31 points:*
[image]

Comment: Perhaps by converting to voronoi polygons your points, and then select 700 polygons that maximize the boundries? But if it is a good idea, I’m not sure to know how to …

Comment: Can you share your data with us?

Comment: Have you also tried the GRASS [`v.cluster`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/v.cluster.html)?

Comment: Here are the points I work with: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/VHBHqyPqreacAms

Comment: @Taras: yes, I tried Grass v.cluster as well, with density clustering method (the others did not produce any result). Did not give a usable result, however

Comment: What kind of clustering are you interested in https://machinelearningmastery.com/clustering-algorithms-with-python/ ? Have you tried to check QGIS Plugins : https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/cluster/. There is one which may be useful : [ClusterPoints](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/clusterpoints/)

Comment: OK - ClusterPoints offers different clustering algorithms. So the problem shifts to the question which one with which parameters produces the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve at least in part what I want to do, even if it is not an exact workflow, more a heuristic approach. So I would still be glad to get better solutions.

What this solution does in an iterative approach and reliably is to create clusters with a maximum numbers of points. A minimum number of points, however cannot be achieved in this way. So I think with this approach, I could reduce the problem to merging contiguous polygons in a way that the sum of an attribute value (no. of points inside the polygon) does not exceed a certain maximum ([see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/433700/88814)).

How the solution works:

1. Create a rough grid - for my region of interest (ca. 40 x 60 km), I choose a 10 km x 10 km grid. **Edit**: I realised that it is better to start with one single grid cell, one that covers the whole extent of the point layer. Like this, one deals with rectangles, not polygons, so the expression in step 4 has to be adapted. The rest remains the same.
2. Count the number of points per grid cell, using this expression (e.g. to create a new attribute `point_count` with Field calculator):

   `array_length (overlay_contains ('point_layer', $id))`
3. Select by expression to select cells that contain no points with the expression `point_count = 0`. Than delete these cells.
4. In a next step, all cells that contain more than a certain number of points (here: 800) should be split in four quadrants (**edit**: for better results, maybe splitting just in two parts would be an option), thus splitting the grid in four smaller polygons so that each contains less points than the initial one. Polygons that already contain a lower number of points than the threshold remain unchanged. To achieve that, I use [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with this expression (**edit**: see at the bottom for the expression if using rectangles in step 1):

   ```
   if (
       point_count > 800,
       collect_geometries (
           make_square( 
               centroid ($geometry), 
               make_point (x_max($geometry), y_max($geometry))
           ),
           make_square( 
               centroid ($geometry), 
               make_point (x_min($geometry), y_max($geometry))
           ),
           make_square( 
               centroid ($geometry), 
               make_point (x_min($geometry), y_min($geometry))
           ),
           make_square( 
               centroid ($geometry), 
               make_point (x_max($geometry), y_min($geometry))
           )
       ),
       $geometry
   )
   ```
5. Convert Multipart to single parts
6. Continue with step 2, as long as there are cells that contain more than to defined number of points (threshold, here: 800).

The result is a layer containing (in my case a number of 1196) square shaped polygons different sizes, containing between 1 and 800 points. There are five different sizes of squares (10 km, 5 km, 2.5 km, 1.25 km, 0.625 km side length) in my case, thus 5 iterations were needed. Now it would be possible to manually merge polygons with just a few points in it with neighboring ones.

*Result: a grid with different sized squares, containing between 1 (white) and 799 (red) points. Left: overview, right: zoomed in to show smaller squares. Labels show the no. of points contained in each polygon:*

[image]

**Edit**

If using a single rectangle covering the whole extent of the point layer instead of a square grid, the solution gives better results. In this case, the expression in step 4 has to be adapted as follows, here used for 1000 instead of 800 points (the rest remains the same):

```
if (
    point_count > 1000,
    collect_geometries(
        make_polygon(
            make_line(
                make_point (x_min($geometry),y_max($geometry)),
                make_point (x_min ($geometry), y_min($geometry)+(y_max($geometry)-y_min ($geometry))/2),
                centroid ($geometry),
                make_point (x_min ($geometry)+(x_max($geometry)-x_min($geometry))/2,y_max($geometry))
            )
        ),
        make_polygon(
            make_line(
                make_point (x_max($geometry),y_max($geometry)),
                make_point (x_min ($geometry)+(x_max($geometry)-x_min($geometry))/2, y_max($geometry)),
                centroid ($geometry),
                make_point (x_max($geometry),y_min($geometry)+(y_max($geometry)-y_min ($geometry))/2)
            )
        ),
        make_polygon(
            make_line(
                centroid ($geometry),
                make_point (x_max($geometry),y_min($geometry)+(y_max($geometry)-y_min ($geometry))/2),
                make_point (x_max($geometry),y_min($geometry)),
                make_point (x_min ($geometry)+(x_max($geometry)-x_min($geometry))/2, y_min($geometry))
            )
        ),
        make_polygon(
            make_line(
                centroid ($geometry),
                make_point (x_min ($geometry)+(x_max($geometry)-x_min($geometry))/2, y_min($geometry)),
                make_point (x_min($geometry),y_min($geometry)),
                make_point (x_min($geometry),y_min($geometry)+(y_max($geometry)-y_min ($geometry))/2)
            )
        )
    ),
    $geometry
)
```

With this variant, I get 943 rectangle shaped polygons of 6 different sizes (7 iterations; the first iteration does not produce any polygons with less then 1000 points) with a range of 1 to 997 points inside the polygons.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of many possible algorithms. Split points cloud in 2,4,8... areas is easy.
One can do it by sequential split of envelope using median X, or median Y coordinate. For example split of 16 for your set will look like this:

[image]

Bad news it will produce multipart polygons after intersect with area of interest. This is why you can split it in smaller (but manageable number) of rectangles (4096 in this case) and group them into 500 clusters using [this algorithm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size-using-arcmap/123297#123297).

[image]
[image]

Statistics of 500 shapes shown in last picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At least theoretically, another approach that could produce something close to the desired result is based on voronoi polygons and cartograms. However, cartograms for this amount of features are hard to calculate, so in the very project here, it is not practicable, but might be so in similar cases with a smaller number of features.

For the clustering itself, correct spatial **position** is not relevant, but the spatial relationship (topology), as only "adjacent" (neighboring) points should be grouped togeter to a cluster. The problem would be relatively easy to solve using a grid if points were more or less evenly spaced. So an approach would be to keep spatial relationship (more or less), but shift the points in a way that they are more evenly spaced.

To achieve this, first create voronoi polygons from the points - like this, the points get "in touch" with each other - there is a spatial relationship like bordering each other. These voronoi polygons will be extremely different in size: small size where point density is high, large size where point density is low.

To get a more or less evenly distributed density of points / more or less similarily sized voronoi polygons, one can create a Cartogram from the voronoi polygons. So voronoi polygons will be distorted in a way that they get more or less the same size / thus distribution of associated points gets more even.

Then apply a regular grid over the distorted voronoi polygons with a size so that the desired number of distorted voronoi polygons fall inside each cell. The list of voronoi's ids (taken from the point ids) inside each cell represents the cluster id. So in the attribute table of each of the distorted voronoi polygon, create a new attribute with the id of the grid cell it (or its centroid) lies within. These are the cluster ids. Then join these cluster ids back to the initial point layer.