Grouping data points based on proximity and minimal count of attribute in QGIS
I am using QGIS to map animal counts on farms in the Midwest US and using a circle polygon to show where there are more than 30,000 animals between all the farms in that specific area. Each data point on the map represents a farm and each farm has a varying amount of animals while each purple circle is an area with at least 30,000 animals.
I have been manually using 'select features by radius' to check if an area has more than 30k animals between all the farms then creating a circle to encapsulate those farms (please see attached picture for example).
Is there a way to automatically create a circle polygon in areas that have at least 30k animals between the farms while also not double-counting data points (farms)? Standard clustering techniques such as K-means and DBSCAN have not worked as I am looking to cluster farms nearby that add up to at least 30,000 animals instead of clustering by density, distance or a consistent attribute.
I have not found any data related to this issue online and have been doing it all manually which is very time-consuming.


See this algorithm https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size-using-arcmap#123297
